# C++11 condtional variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying make a lot of mistakes to learn Concurrency in C++11. I have to ask this,
Here is what this one is supposed to do:
One queue, and three threads, one is suppose to put an integer into the queue, the other twos are suppose to correspondingly increase s1, s2 by popping the queue so that I can get total sum of numbers that were in the queue. To make it simpler I put 1 through 10 numbers into the queue.

But sometimes it works and sometimes it seems like there is an infinite loop:: what would be the reason?

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <string>

class threadsafe_queue {
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<int> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
    std::string log; //just to see what is going on behind
    bool done;

public:
    threadsafe_queue(){
        log = "initializing queue\n";
        done = false;
    }
    threadsafe_queue(threadsafe_queue const& other) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
        data_queue = other.data_queue;
    }
    void set_done(bool const s) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        done = s;
    }
    bool get_done() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        return done;
    }
    void push(int new_value) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        log += "+pushing " + std::to_string(new_value) + "\n";
        data_queue.push(new_value);
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }
    void wait_and_pop(int& value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
        value = data_queue.front();
        log += "-poping " + std::to_string(value) + "\n";
        data_queue.pop();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<int> wait_and_pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty();});
        std::shared_ptr<int> res(std::make_shared<int>(data_queue.front()));
        log += "- popping " + std::to_string(*res) + "\n";
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }
    bool try_pop(int& value) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty()) {
            log += "tried to pop but it was empty\n";
            return false;
        }
        value = data_queue.front();
        log += "-popping " + std::to_string(value) + "\n";
        data_queue.pop();
        return true;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<int> try_pop() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty()) {
            log += "tried to pop but it was empty\n";
            return std::shared_ptr<int>();
        }
        std::shared_ptr<int> res(std::make_shared<int>(data_queue.front()));
        log += "-popping " + std::to_string(*res) + "\n";
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }
    bool empty() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        //log += "checking the queue if it is empty\n";
        return data_queue.empty();
    }

    std::string get_log() {
        return log;
    }

};

threadsafe_queue tq;
int s1, s2;

void prepare() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        tq.push(i);
    tq.set_done(true);
}

void p1() {
    while (true) {
        int data;
        tq.wait_and_pop(data);
        s1 += data;
        if (tq.get_done() && tq.empty()) break;
    }
}

void p2() {
    while (true) {
        int data;
        tq.wait_and_pop(data);
        s2 += data;
        if (tq.get_done() && tq.empty()) break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::thread pp(prepare);
    std::thread worker(p1);
    std::thread worker2(p2);
    pp.join();
    worker.join();
    worker2.join();

    std::cout << tq.get_log() << std::endl;
    std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to notify `data_cond` when setting `done` and check it in `data_cond.wait` condition.

Comment: I think you get deadlock if `wait_and_pop()` is called before `push()`, as `push()` cannot get past the mutex to call `notify_one` to free `wait_and_pop()` from its wait. I think you should `wait()` *before* grabbing the mutex lock.

Comment: @KenY-N, yes that is what I was suspecting. But how do I make it sure that push() should work before anything?

Comment: @Nano As I said, try swapping `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);` and `data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty();});`. This ensures that the code doesn't pop until something's been pushed. (I think; this is all off the top of my head!) And you maybe want `data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut); return !data_queue.empty();});`, or just redesign your whole code!

Comment: @KenY-N No, you cannot swap these lines, they are in the correct order. Read on how `std::condition_variable::wait` works.

Answer (score 1):

Look at function p1 line 5

> if (tq.get_done() && tq.empty()) break;

So you checked the queue if it was empty. It was not. Now you loop and enter

> tq.wait_and_pop(data);

where you'll find

> data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty();});

which is essentially

> while (data_queue.empty()) {
>       wait(lk);
>   }

notice the missing '!'.

Now your thread sits there and waits for the queue not to be empty, which will never happen, because the producer id done filling the queue. The thread will never join.

There are many ways to fix this. I'm sure you'll find one on your own.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true too. If `p2` empties the queue between `p1`'s `tq.empty()` and the next `tq.wait_and_pop(data);` there will be another hang.

Comment: @Nano: If my answer satisfied your question, think about add that green little tick right next to my answer. ty